# displaying values of a card using bits in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I have a card game where I need to display the value of the card after I shuffle I display the value of the card using values `(x >> 1)& 0xf` where x iterates through the list of 13 cards this is found as bit 1-4 is the value of the card

the above is card type

But when I come across finding the highest pair in the card it only works when I use `values[(afterfindingpairs[a]&0xf0)>>4]`.

This is worked out as 0-4 bits are the no of pairs whereas the 4-7 bits are the values of the pair in the byte of pair type.

It just displays the highest pair as Ace when I use

`values[(afterfindingpairs[a]&0xf)>>4]`.

I'm confused wouldnt the hexadecimal 0xf0 deal with 8 bits rather than the 4 bit between 4-7 of the pair type which would be found by `values[(afterfindingpairs[a]&0xf)>>4]` which is incorrect.

Explanation as to why this happens  would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note: It would make your question significantly clearer if you actually documented *how **exactly*** the rank and suit are intended to be stored in your bit pattern. You may have been staring at it so long it is etched in your retinas; we haven't. And a few samples speak *volumes*.

Comment: could you clarify this with some example of actual values of cards packed into your bit pattern?  For instance the ace of diamonds is...what?  Also you mention "he hexadecimal 0xf0 deal with 8 bits" do you mean 0xf0 or 0xf ???

Comment: WhozCraig the rank is stored between 1-4 and suit is stored in 5 & 6 bit and bit 7 is unused for card type and 0-3 bits for no of pairs 4-7 bits  for value in pair type.

Vorsprung 0xf0 deals with 8 bits and 0xf deals with 4 bits

Comment: sample run
Ace of Diamonds is Red in binary 00000000

Comment: `(Value & 0xf) >> 4` will likely always be 0. You're and'ing away all the top bits, and then shifting away all the bottom bits.

Comment: jasonD wouldnt Value & 0xf >> 4 only take the last 4 bits and the first 4 bits could be anything but if we take 0xf0 >> 4  would take 8 bits starting from 4  but we want only 4 bits am I right

Comment: No, that's not right at all.

Comment: did u mean top bits as in 0-4 and 4-7 as bottom bits and also 0xf0 wouldnt the binary occupy all 8 bits and wouldnt have space to shift at all ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to want to manipulate 8-bit values, extracting various ranges of bits. However in some cases you're doing so in such a way as to discard *all* the bits.

The 8 bits are arranged from least significant (bit 0, which is '1' in decimal), to the most significant (bit 7, which is '128' in decimal).

So if we had the binary number `10010110`, this would represent the number (128 + 16 + 4 + 2), or 150, or 0x96 in hex.

If you apply a right-shift to such a number, the bits will be moved to the right by the appropriate number of places. So if we did `>>4` to the number above, the result will be `00001001` - or 9. I have assumed we are dealing with unsigned values here, so the upper bits will be filled in with '0'. Note that the result is that the original bits 4-7 are now bits 0-3, and the original bits 0-3 have been discarded.

If you `and` two numbers, the result is that only bits which are set in both will be set in the result. So effectively this is masking bits. If you mask with `0xf0`, this is in binary `11110000`, so only the upper bits, 4-7 will remain in the result, and the lower bits 0-3 will be set to zero.

Take your statement:

```
values[(afterfindingpairs[a]&0xf0)>>4]
```

The expression `afterfindingpairs[a]&0xf0`, as per my explanation above, will simply set bits 0-3 to zero, retaining bits 4-7.

The next part of the expression, `>>4` will shift those remaining bits down so they become bits 0-3 of the result. Note that this *also* discards the original bits 0-3, making the previous mask operation redundant (unless we are *not* dealing with 8-bit values...)

Your other statement:

```
values[(afterfindingpairs[a]&0xf)>>4]
```

Is more problematic. You first apply a mask (`0xf`) retains only bits 0-3, setting all others to zero. Then you apply a shift which throws away bits 0-3, by shifting bits 4-7 (which are already zero) down into their place.

In other words, this latter expression is always zero.